# Dynamic allocation for struct in c

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, struct, allocation

Hello everyone this is my first question so if I do something wrong ,please forgive me.

I have been trying to allocate memory for the struct I have written.definition as follows;

```
struct newstruct* temp1;
temp1 = malloc(1*sizeof(struct newstruct));
```

whenever I tried to allocate memory like this I always get the "[Warning] incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'malloc'" warning.
I don't understand if my definition wrong or I am missing anything.

Comment: You need to read the manual for `malloc` and discover which header declares it.

Comment: @KerrekSB and upvoters: if he is asking this question he is literally just getting started.  He doesn't need to read the reference manual, a notoriously tedious and dry technical dump, he needs to get better at [Googling C errors](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=[Warning]%20incompatible%20implicit%20declaration%20of%20built-in%20function%20%27malloc%27).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

to your includes.